# SQL Server + Eloquent conversion datetime in query/results

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

In my project I am using Eloquent as db layer. And I have big issue with conversion datetime object.

There are 3 servers:

1. SQL Server
2. Production (PHP)
3. Local develop

Production and local develop is connecting to SQL Server and sending queries.

Part of query where I am working with datetime:

```
$builder->where("register.from", '>=', $filter->getDateFrom()->setTime(0, 0, 0))
```

`->getDateFrom()` returns a `\DateTime` php object.

And on linux machine is this code working fine... But problems starts on Local develop machine with win 10 and xampp server.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I am on end line now. Can anybody help?

After remove all dates from query i was get the same message about converting data but in 'id' context... I was problem with 'id' as integers in query for joining tables...

> SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'hladiny.IDENT_HL' to data type int.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

On SQL Server is user with default date format: 'dmy' and default language 'čeština' but a lot of time i was try it works on 'en_english'. Driver sqlsrv is for version php 7.2 and is thread safe for x86 (if i was trying x64 it not work)

Also i was trying install ODBC 13. Same results.